# NullReferenceException on ForEach JSON c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I am having a problem with the following code.  It uses the Facebook c# SDK.  The problem is that I am pulling and printing a list of all of my friends work history.  However, when this data isn't available I think it is causing a NullReferenceException.  I have looked at a bunch of solutions online, but haven't found one that seems to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var accessToken = "...";
        var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        dynamic myInfo = client.Get("me/friends", new { fields = "name,id,work" });

        foreach (dynamic friend in myInfo)
        {
            foreach (dynamic work in myInfo.work) // <---- here
            {
                Response.Write("Employer: " + work.employer.name + "<br/> Position:" + work.position.name + "<br/><br/>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have included the suggested edits but am now getting a different error:

```
    namespace WebApplication1.Site
 {
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var accessToken = "xxx";
        var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        dynamic myInfo = client.Get("me/friends", new { fields = "name,id,work" });

        foreach (dynamic friend in myInfo)
        {
            **foreach (dynamic work in friend.work ?? new[] { new { employer = new { name = string.Empty }, position = new { name = string.Empty } } })**
                {
                    Response.Write("Employer: " + myInfo.work.employer.name);
                }

        }


    }
}
}
```

'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair' does not contain a definition for 'work' on Line 21

Comment: You might want to check if work.employer is null before trying to access the name property. And likewise for the position name.

Comment: I noticed you are using dynamic with JSON and work may not exist instead of being null, try my second edit that uses the ?? operator with the anonymous type. Also remove the `if (friend.work == null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide an empty list to inplace of the null value to avoid the null reference exception:

```
 foreach (dynamic work in friend.work ?? new List<string>())
```

You are getting the exception because foreach makes a call to .GetEnumerator() on a null value. I used a new List, but it doesn't really matter what is put here.. as long as it isn't null and it is enumerable.

**Edit**

You could provide an anonymous type that provides the properties you need:

```
 foreach (dynamic work in friend.work ?? new [] { new { employer = new { name = string.Empty}, position = new { name = string.Empty }}})
```

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>' does not contain a definition for 'work'

Comment: The code does run like this: foreach (dynamic work in myInfo.work ?? new List<string>())

but it just produces a blank page... however no errors.

Comment: @RaySülzer Check my edit, you need to check to see if it's null if you want to write an error message. My first example just prevents the null reference exception.

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>' does not contain a definition for 'work'

The problem is that there are about 19000 work fields under 800 friends.  I want to go through all of them and when there isn't a work field to skip it.

Comment: @RaySülzer In the if statment for `(friend.work == null)` you can put that blank output, it will run only when then work property is null.

Comment: @RaySülzer My first example will skip it, if you want to provide a blank output each time there is no work field then see my second edit.

Comment: Thanks @dmck.    The problem is now that I get these three errors on that line of code.  The name employer does not exist in the current context, the name position does not exist in the current context, no best type found for impicitly-typed array.

Comment: @RaySülzer try again with my most recent edit, there were a couple syntax errors. It should now initialize the array as a anonymous array with a single value.

Comment: that did fix all of those errors, but now it's another thing.  I feel really bad.  This is my first time working in C#, I am a VB.NET programmer. :(

Comment: @RaySülzer Can you mark this as the solution and post a new question? Please post the link and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802828/system-collections-generic-keyvaluepairstring-object-does-not-contain-a-defi

Answer (score 0):

Just test myInfo.work for null before starting the inner loop:

```
if (myInfo.work != null) {
   foreach (dynamic work in myInfo.work)
```

Also, I just noticed you may be using the wrong object:

```
if (friend.work != null) {
   foreach (dynamic work in friend.work)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the API, but I'm guessing in your inner loop you probably mean to be iterating over a property of the object created in the outer loop.

For example:

```
foreach (dynamic friend in myInfo)
{
    foreach (dynamic work in friend.work) // rather than myInfo.work
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You should also probably have a null check around your inner loop, to guard against null reference exceptions.